# Ignore pycharm breakpoint for first N hits

Tags: python, pycharm, breakpoints

I'm trying to ignore a specific breakpoint in pycharm for the first N times it hits.  Since I'm looking to set it to something like 10k, manually doing this is not an option.  I found the expanded options for breakpoints, including the `condition` field, but I'm not sure how I can craft a condition which takes into account how many times the breakpoint has been hit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can just create a variable in Python specifically for the breakpoint counting purpose, which you increment every time you you go past the break point line. Then just use that variable in your break point condition (i.e. `breakpoint_count == 10000`).

**Update**

If you can't add new code into the real python code you can use the breakpoint condition:

`eval("exec('try:\\n    x += 1\\nexcept NameError:\\n    x = 1') or x == 10000")`

What this does is execute a try statement which increments a variable or creates it if it doesn't exist. Then evaluates that along with a statement checking if the variable has been incremented enough times yet with that being your ending condition. Note, the `exec` is required to run the `try`, but the `eval` is needed to "return" the condition to PyCharm. This is absurdly hacky, but it works for your case!

Comment: I had considered that, but I was looking to use this on a breakpoint inside a python library and so editing it was not so easy

Comment: @portforwardpodcast, my update should work for your then.